# Problem importing Excel File with openpyxl (file path problem)

Tags: python, excel, macos, path, openpyxl

I am trying to load an .xlsx file with the openpyxl module. The below file path works with the xlrd module, but I have tried this and multiple other versions including just "pytestsheet.xlsx" with openpyxl. Each time I get a FILENOTFOUNDERROR. This is on a Mac.

```
import openpyxl
path = "~/Documents/pytestsheet.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

Comment: `~` isn't automatically expanded like it is in the shell... you need to explicitly do it, eg: `os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/pytestsheet.xlsx")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this function you need the full path (you can't just use the tilde), e.g.

```
import openpyxl
path = "/Users/wogsland/Documents/pytestsheet.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

replacing my username with whatever yours is.

Comment: Which you don't need to hard code - instead use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: Alright I think we're making progress but now there a different error message for both the full path and os.path. Now am getting an error that says '''UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg) ''' and doesn't appear to perform the commands either. Do I need to download a different version of openpyxl or save the file somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: @blRVA15 I'd recommend asking another question with the details of which file extension you're using and what version of openpyxl. `.xlsx` works fine for me.

Comment: @wogsland sorry for the vague previous question but got it to work! Just added the following to get rid of the message: "' >>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, read_only= True, data_only= True)"' . Thanks for your time and help!